# OnBindView is only called when getItemCount returns 1 greater than array size

Tags: android, android-studio, android-adapter

I've encountered a weird bug where no cards are displayed by the adapter if `getItemCount` returns 1 (size of data structure).

**My Adapter Code -**

```
public class SingleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SingleAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    public SingleAdapter() {
        names.add("Rajma Chawal"); //Just for testing purposes
    }

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CardView cardView;
    public ViewHolder(CardView v) {
        super(v);
        cardView=v;
    }
}

@Override
public SingleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_order, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(cv);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
    TextView textView = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.info_name);
    textView.setText(names.get(position));
}

public int getItemCount() {
    return names.size();
//        return 2;   Generates a card if I do this 
//and put a constant in place of Textview.setText("kk"); like this.
// Otherwise occurs in an outofbounds exception
}
```

I don't know why it requires me to have 1 in the count, as otherwise no cards are generated. I'm a beginner, so I'm sorry if this question is too trivial.

Edit: I checked around with arrays, looks like it must be some problem with Arraylists as such, arrays are normally.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked normally.

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice the `return 2;` part. You can't return 2 while the list's size is 1. Add the extra item to your `ArrayList` in the constructor while passing your data.

Comment: @MohanadMohie I think what @Rajat is saying is that he is getting one less item than `itemcount`.

Comment: @Abbas yes, if the list is of size 10 I can display only 9 cards. If the list of size 1 nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest please look at how you are adding data into list. Might be you are doing some thing wrong with arraylist. But in `getItemCount()` method condition should be like that.
It will never crash anymore. It might be helpful then.

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return _cursor == null ? 0 : _cursor.sortedKeys().size();
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with the way I pass item count, but yeah, it could be a problem with the data structure as such, since a similar code with arrays works, I'll try and give it a shot ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

`getItemCount()` tells the `Adapter` that how many rows are there to display. if the `List` is of size zero that means there are no rows to display in the `RecyclerView`.

Now when you add a entry ( which you are doing in the `Constructor`) the size of the `list` changes to one. Then the `Adapter` calls the `getItemCount()` which returns the size of the `list` ( which is now one) and populates the `Adapter` accordingly.

Comment: That is what is not happening. For a list of size 1 I've to return 2 for the card to display and so on.

Comment: i am not sure about this weird behaviour. but in that case you can use : `return name.size()  + 1 ; `

Comment: I know I can use that. But then it gives an aout of bounds exception. I have to check for that position in onBindView method again. And its not at all consistent. Works sometimes, other times just does nothing. I guess it's a problem with ArrayLists, I'll try and see if arrays do any good.